# pyral query no longer finds Rally tickets

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I'm using the Python plugin pyral.

I connect to Rally like this:

```
r = pyral.Rally(apikey="<My ID>", project="<My top level project>")
```

And then I search for a Rally story like this:

```
resp = r.get("UserStory", fetch=True, query='FormattedID = "{}"'.format(ID))
```

where ID is the Rally ticket #, something like AB12345.

This used to work but now it returns zero results. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it now, by default, only searches the top level project and not the children projects.

I changed my call to this and it was able to find the ticket again:

```
resp = r.get("UserStory", fetch=True, projectScopeDown=True, query='FormattedID = "{}"'.format(ID))
```